# Postgres Using Hstore in Schema giving error that Operator Does Not Exist

Tags: postgresql

I have enabled Hstore extension in public

When trying to insert from from actual schema it is giving error "Function Hstore does not exist"

I do not have permission to alter any thing in DB, can I use public prefix and get this done

```
update my_table 
set hstore_column = coalesce(hstore_column, hstore(array[]::varchar[])) || '"a"=>"b"' where id ='ABCD';
```

I have tried like this

```
update my_table 
set hstore_column = coalesce(hstore_column, public.hstore(array[]::varchar[])) || public.hstore('"a"=>"b"') 
where id ='ABCD';
```

I get this error

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: public.hstore || public.hstore
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 103
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: public.hstore || public.hstore
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 103
```

Comment: Try `public.hstore(...)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: public.hstore || public.hstore
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 103
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: public.hstore || public.hstore
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 103